# How to actualise/refresh the external XSD resource in PhpStorm

Tags: xml, xsd, phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2019.1, all the time I do some changes in XSD files and upload on an external server, xml files inside others project using this xsd got errors because the external XSD Ressource is stored in `C:\Users\Peter\user\.PhpStorm2019.1\system\extResources\my-xsd.xsd` and I do not manage to actualise it.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try storing it in a project using relative paths. See more at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215664 - feel free to comment it since the problem isn't actually addressed yet.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will follow that.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, the best way I found is removed the `C:\Users\Peter\user\.PhpStorm2019.1\system\extResources\my-xsd.xsd` to let phpstorm to get the last one.

So in your xml...

1. focus in the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute, and let the lamp icon appears
2. click on the lamp icon and in the menu select `Manualy Setup External Ressource`
3. select your .xsd (if it´s necessary) and on the right of "file" input click on `...`
4. remove the xsd file and close the window
5. Do change in `xsi:schemaLocation` to get the link in grey and click on "Fetch External resource" in the lamp menu